# Basic protected folder redirecting to https 401 page and causing problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

So I am redirecting all requests to my site to the www and https version MINUS one folder.  That one folder just happens to be password protected.  I need to access that folder with regular http (the reason for excluding it from the redirects), but when I do that it gives a 401 error.  If I access it with https then the browser prompts me for the user/pass as normal.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**/public_html/ htaccess**

```
# BEGIN non-www to www with https: (with exclusions)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/protected/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**/public_html/protected/ htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Access"
require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/protected/passwd"
```

**Problem**

As I am excluding this folder from the www and https redirects I 'should' be able to access any files in /protected/ by either http OR https.  The problem is http://example.com/protected/somefile.htm redirects to the https 401 error page without even prompting me for a user/pass.

On the other hand https://example.com/protected/somefile.htm works fine - it prompts me for the user/pass and works great.

For one I don't understand why this is happening and two I must be able to access files in that folder with http and non-ssl.

I should add that the htaccess rules are 'correct' as if I comment out the lines for the user/pass on protected it works as it should and both http/https are able to be served.  It is ONLY when the folder is pw'ed that this problem is happening.